# Counting the ways items can be distributed over boxes with and without order important in the boxes.

Tags: combinatorics

Say there are 5 distinguishable boxes and 10 numbered items, that need to be distributed uniformly and randomly over the boxes. In how many ways can this be done if
a. the order in the boxes matters?
b. the order in the boxes does not matter?

Solving question a: I imagine taking a random item, randomly choose a box, and repeat this until all items are placed. This way, if box 1 contains items 1 and 2, both items could be on top, so we see that order in the boxes matters.
My answer is 5^10.

Solving question b: I imagine taking item number 1, place it, then item 2 and so forth till finally item 10 is placed. In this way, in a box with more than one item, item 1 is always on the bottom, and item 10 is always on top in the box they end up. I think we can say order in the boxes does not matter. There will only be one order per box.
But my answer would still be 5^10.

It seems obvious to me that the answer to questions a. and b. can't be the same.
Wondering where I do go wrong?

Comment: Try with two boxes and two items.  With one method you have the four possibilities $(\{A,B\},\{\,\})$, $(\{A\},\{B\})$, $(\{B\},\{A\})$, $(\{\,\},\{A,B\})$ while with the other method you have the six $((A,B),(\,))$, $((B,A),(\,))$, $((A),(B))$, $((B),(A))$, $((\,),(A,B))$, $((\,),(B,A))$.  Clearly only the first is $2^2$

Comment: @Henry Yes indeed. It just seemed to me that the methods for problem a. and b. were in fact the same. Well, they are not, but I found this so odd. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For question b, I think the answer is $5^{10}$.
For question a,\
Consider the case that the 10 items are distributed to 2 of the 10 boxes, then there are $P_{10}^{2}$ choices, 10 items can be equal to 1+9, 2+8, 3+7, 4+6, 5+5, we just take the 3+7 case for example, we have chosen 2 boxes for the 3+7 items to place in,then we consider how to place the 3+7 items.
In the box where 3 items are placed in, there are $P_{3}^{3}=3!$ choices as the order matters, similarly, there are 7! choices for the 7-item-box.
Using this method to solve the problem can be complex, but I think it's a good way to understand why the answer can't be $5^{10}$.\
To solve the question, we can use the stars and bars method. We have 10 items (stars) to distribute among 5 distinguishable boxes. We need to place 4 dividers (bars) to separate the items into the 5 boxes. The order in the boxes matters, so we need to consider all possible arrangements of stars and bars.\
So the answer may be $\binom{14}{4}\cdot P_{10}^{10}=\frac{14!}{4!}.$(Changes are made thanks to @Henry in the comment)

Comment: I think that is too large.  If you were going to arrange $10$ numbered balls and $5-1=4$ dividers in $14!$ ways, you might say those give you $4!$ potential orderings  of the dividers when you only want one, so your result would be $\frac{14!}{4!}$

Comment: @Henry Thanks, you are right. I overcounted because I noticed that the boxes are distinguishable so I considered the order of the boxes which was not needed.

Comment: @Aaron Lee Yes indeed. It just seemed to me that the methods for problem a. and b. were in fact the same. Well, they are not, as your answer clearly shows. Thanks.